# sending a canvas image over socket.io

Tags: html, canvas, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am trying to move my `Base64` images to `Buffers` made available in `Socket.io 1.0`

I load images with `FileReader()` and resize them with the `Canvas` element.

`Canvas` has a still pretty unsupported `.toBlob()`, anybody has a more compatible way of sending my canvas / image as a `arraybuffer` over the socket which will also let me open buffer on the other side and make it a canvas / image again.

Comment: The 1.0 version of Socket.IO will initially establish an XHR or JSONP connection and will then attempt to replace that connection with a websocket connection if websockets are available. This is a valuable flexibility for clients that don't support websockets. That flexibility will be lost if you send your data packets as binary-only.

Comment: why would that flexibility be lost? And can't i only send images as binary?

Comment: As you mentioned, toBlob support is not widely available transmitting binary blobs in older browsers will fail.  Base64 encoding results in a string value which can be sent in any version of browser & socketIO--much more flexible.

Comment: yeah toBlob is not a good way to go, thats why i was looking for another way; like using the canvas imagedata `Uint8clampedArray`, but i cannot seem to convert that back to an image.

Answer (score 7):

You can use canvas.toDataURL and send that base64 encoded dataURL using socketIO.

```
var theDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

The dataURL is a .PNG representation of the image.  You can also specify a .JPEG representation if you need a smaller file size canvas.

```
// quality ranges from 0.00-1.00
var jpgQuality=0.60;

// get the dataURL in .jpg format
var theDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',jpgQuality);
```

Both the .png and .jpg dataURL formats are more lightweight than transporting the pixel array from `context.getImageData`.  The pixel array weighs in at canvas.width*canvas.height*4 while the .png and .jpg formats are compressed/optimized during encoding.

Base64 encoding results in a string so it's compatible with all browsers and all fallback versions of socketIO transport.

Then you can easily deserialize the dataURL on the receiving side like this:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src=theBase64URL;
function start(){
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    // or
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for you awnser Mark, good to know that the pixelarray is larger! Im curious if this counts for any other Buffer/File types i could possibly send over socket.io